# How to remove a lock ring if there is no cassette?

Tags: wheels

A friend tightened the lockring without the cassette on, and now we can't use the chain whip to unscrew it. It's on a road bike wheel if that matters. I'm looking for tools and ideas to undo this.

I found this post on a forum, but I'm looking for more answers
https://www.lfgss.com/conversations/303374/

Comment: Can you remove the freehub from the hub with the lock ring in place? This opens a heap of options. 

Carefully grind or mill the lock ring down to remove the lip, so you can slid a cassette on.  Fabricate a tool that will clamp around the freewheel and mesh with the splines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pad the freehub body with rags, hold it with a big pipe wrench or vice grips.

Another possibility is holding the freehub body pointing downwards in a vice with plastic soft-jaws (or padded with rags, again). If you position the freehub at the side of the jaws you can probably get the lockring tool in underneath.

Comment: I'd look at sliding pliers, aka plumbers pliers around the freehub body, and a lot of padding.  The freehub is likely steel and will cope with this force.

Comment: It's probably worth degreasing the freehub first. Clean and dry, a ruined inner tube is good for soft jaws or wrapping round the freehub. Cable ties can secure it if they don't get in the way of the pliers

Comment: A thick piece of leather from a discarded belt is probably better than rubber, less shearing.

Answer (score 6):

Use a strap wrench on the freehub body.